# setting the state with the switch instruction in the react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to set the state with the switch instruction in the manner given below? Or maybe none of these ways is a good solution

Can I set:

```
return this.setState({
         stat1: 'a'
       })
```

or

`return this.state.stat1 = 'a'`

**First way**

```
    books = (price) => {
      switch(price) {
        case 100:
          return this.setState({
            stat1: 'a'
          })
        case 1000:
          return this.setState({
            stat1: 'b'
          })
        case 2000:
          return this.setState({
            stat1: 'c'
          })
        default:
          return this.setState({
            stat1: ''
          })
      }
    }
```

**Second way**

```
    books = (price) => {
      switch(price) {
        case 100:
          return this.state.stat1 = 'a'   
        case 1000:
          return this.state.stat1 = 'b'
        case 2000:
          return this.state.stat1 = 'c'
        default:
          return this.state.stat1 = ''
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well u can use first way but this how u can do it also:

```
const books = price => {
this.setState({
  stat1: price===100?"a"
        :price===1000?"b"
        :price===2000?"c"
        :null
   })
 }
```

second way is wrong check this for explanation [Why we can't change states in react without calling setState()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51426496/why-we-cant-change-states-in-react-without-calling-setstate)

Comment: Maybe? --> `books = price => {
this.setState({
  stat1: price===100?"a":
        price===1000?"b":
        price===2000?"c":  ' '                                                                                  
   })
 }`

Comment: @umbro forgot to add last else check  answer now! it should work!

Answer (score 0):

Since React state should be treated as immutable, you shouldn't set state by assigning a new value directly (i.e. `this.state.stat1 = 'a'`). So only the first way you provided works.

However, the `setState` setter does not have an explicit return value. As a result, the value of `books` will always be `undefined`.

Comment: Except he's missed out the default case.

Answer (score 0):

Your "First way" should work. Because you cant assign values to e state like  solution 2

Answer (score 0):

**We can not use this way.**

```
return this.state.stat1 = 'a'
```

it will not render after state is updated and that's why we will not able see the change on the screen. we need to use the setState() method only. and I think you should try to use Async/ await it might help, 1st try without it and then try with async/await.

```
books = async (price) => {
      switch(price) {
        case 100:
          return await this.setState({
            stat1: 'a'
          })
        case 1000:
          return await this.setState({
            stat1: 'b'
          })
        case 2000:
          return await this.setState({
            stat1: 'c'
          })
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
setPrice = (price) => {
    this.setState(() => ({ stat1: ({100: "a", 1000: "b", 2000: "c"})[price] }))
}
```